# Welcome Page not set when creating a sharepoint site based on a publishing custom site template

Tags: sharepoint-2010

After I save a enterprise publishing site as a site template and then try to create a subsite based on the site template that I just created, the site is created, but browser doesn't take me to the default page. After doing some digging I've found that the Welcome page url value is not set right, for example: http://sharepointsite:55555/SubSite/ is the welcome page url value after creating the siste and where I think it should be http://sharepointsite:55555/SubSite/defualt.aspx?

Help Please, I've been struggling with this issue for a couple of days now.

Thank You,

Answer (score 0):

Saving a publishing site as a site template is not supported. Activating the publishing feature disables the "`Save site as template` option".

How are you trying to save it as template ?

Comment: Accessing the savetmpl.aspx file. I notice that feature when I turn it on I don't have the option, but when I turn it off it appears? Why is that, and do you have documentation to support this?

Comment: Its not a bug. The Save site as template feature is not supported with Publishing feature.http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2007/09/19/save-site-as-template-option-and-the-publishing-feature.aspx

Comment: thanks for the link, what about the other issue? Have you seen this before?

Comment: Regarding the welcome page not displaying after creating a subsite based on my custom publishing site template?

Comment: Since the saving as template itself is not supported, we can not be sure of any unexpected behaviour arising out of that template...